# React Rails components won't work Rails 5.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I installed `react-rails` since I want to use rails on my Rails 5.2.4 application.

When I installed it, I basically got the following order on my `app/javascripts/` directory:

```
components [directory]
---.keep file
packs [directory]
---applicationCache.js
---hello_react.jsx
---server_rendering.jsx
```

Inside my components directory I've added a file called `appointments.jsx` inside `app\javascripts\components\' which I link to my Appointments controller and views via`<%= react_component 'Appointments' %>`here is the content of the`appointments.jsx` file:

```
const Appointments = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello Appointments</h1>
      </div>
    );
};
```

Since I already link this to my index view via `<%= react_component 'Appointments' %>`  I expected this to display an h1 tag with the text `Hello Appointments` on it on my root (i already set this up on my routes.rb file) instead I got the ff errors on my console:

```
Hello World from Webpacker
fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js:21 Error: Cannot find module './Appointments'
    at webpackContextResolve (.*$:13)
    at webpackContext (.*$:8)
    at fromRequireContext.js:13
    at Object.getConstructor (fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js:15)
    at Object.mountComponents (index.js:89)
    at HTMLDocument../node_modules/react_ujs/react_ujs/index.js.ReactRailsUJS.handleMount (index.js:149)
    at Object.e.dispatch (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7)
    at turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
(anonymous) @ fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js:21
mountComponents @ index.js:89
./node_modules/react_ujs/react_ujs/index.js.ReactRailsUJS.handleMount @ index.js:149
e.dispatch @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7
r.pageLoaded @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7
(anonymous) @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js:22 ReferenceError: Appointments is not defined
    at eval (eval at ./node_modules/react_ujs/react_ujs/src/getConstructor/fromGlobal.js.module.exports (fromGlobal.js:12), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at ./node_modules/react_ujs/react_ujs/src/getConstructor/fromGlobal.js.module.exports (fromGlobal.js:12)
    at Object.getConstructor (fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js:19)
    at Object.mountComponents (index.js:89)
    at HTMLDocument../node_modules/react_ujs/react_ujs/index.js.ReactRailsUJS.handleMount (index.js:149)
    at Object.e.dispatch (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7)
    at turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
(anonymous) @ fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js:22
mountComponents @ index.js:89
./node_modules/react_ujs/react_ujs/index.js.ReactRailsUJS.handleMount @ index.js:149
e.dispatch @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7
r.pageLoaded @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7
(anonymous) @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
index.js:100 [react-rails] Cannot find component: 'Appointments' for element <div data-react-class=​"Appointments" data-react-props=​"{}​" data-react-cache-id=​"Appointments-0">​</div>​
index.js:103 Uncaught Error: Cannot find component: 'Appointments'. Make sure your component is available to render.
    at Object.mountComponents (index.js:103)
    at HTMLDocument../node_modules/react_ujs/react_ujs/index.js.ReactRailsUJS.handleMount (index.js:149)
    at Object.e.dispatch (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6)
    at r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7)
    at r.pageLoaded (turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7)
    at turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
mountComponents @ index.js:103
./node_modules/react_ujs/react_ujs/index.js.ReactRailsUJS.handleMount @ index.js:149
e.dispatch @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
r.notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7
r.pageLoaded @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7
(anonymous) @ turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
```

For the record here's the content of my `application.js` file under `app/packs/` directory:

```
console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')
// Support component names relative to this directory:
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here? Why does the text not showing up on view?

Comment: There seem to be some mixed information. First you're showing a `app/javascripts/` folder that have an `applicationCache.js` file and at the end of your question you're talking about an `application.js` in a `app/packs` folder. Can you please review your question and ensure the given information are coherent?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I am only showing the errors as well as the content of the files I am working with.

Comment: Sure you're doing it, but you seem to given wrong information (different paths and  filenames). Please read again your question and my comment, you should spot it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you export your component? I.e. `export default Appointments;`.
Also it could be a case sensitivity issue, i.e. you are calling it with upper case `react_component 'Appointments'` and have `appointments.jsx`.

Comment: @JoanBuan yep, just write it as a last line inside Appointements.jsx, i.e. `export default Appointments;`